# Область видимости переменных. Почему так?

Tags: c#

У нас есть два вложенных выражения `using`. Один вложен в другой почему внешний `using` не может работать с переменными внутреннего .

### **UPD**:

нужно, сделать правку:) я только учу язык. у нас есть вложенные блоки. Давайте я уточню, какая цель у разработчика языка внести такие ограничения чтобы вложенные видели внешние переменные, а наоборот не получается .

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(targetPath, enc))
{
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sourcePath, true, enc))
  { 
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А вы можете, водя автомобиль, работать с двигателем к примеру

Comment: Что должен иллюстрировать данный код? Он выглядит вполне рабочим

Comment: Это явление называется областью видимости переменных, и в С# сделана такая реализация.

Comment: @Grundy она хочет что бы в внешнем блоке был доступ к переменным вложенного блока

Comment: @SeeSharp, ты уверен, что именно в этом был вопрос?

Comment: @Grundy вопрос из группы не "почему не работает", а "почему так нельзя".  Она привела работающий код, но искажение его даже не скомпилируется.

Comment: @Grundy дабы избежать таких дискусий, стоило бы править вопрос, и указать конкретную проблему.

Comment: @SeeSharp, что ты имеешь ввиду под искажением?

Comment: @Grundy: **SeeSharp** верно говорит. Гражданка ТС хочет использовать переменную `line` вне блока `using ... sw...`. Так что вопрос не про `using`, а про области видимости

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: @Grundy: я просто за все время нахождения здесь научился понимать не совсем ясные вопросы пользователей ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ответ: так задумано разработчиками языка. Вопрос был бы интереснее, если бы вы спросили почему разработчики языка вели такие ограничения.

Comment: @АндрейNOP только тогда уже применительно не к C#, а более старшим и местами забытым языкам, от которых это унаследовано =)

Comment: @rdorn, ну тут тоже не так просто все. В том же JavaScript те же фигурные скобки, но области видимости для var-переменных размыты

Answer (score 2):

Что такое using вообще? Это некий логический блок с создаваемой переменной и при этом который помечает ВСЕ переменные внутри на освобождение как только мы вышли за границу using.

Что же из этого выходит?

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(targetPath, enc))//мы создали переменную sr
{
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sourcePath, true, enc)) //мы создали переменную sw
  { 
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

    }
  }//до этой строки включительно мы можем использовать sw
//Здесь sw мы уже не можем использовать ибо она УЖЕ помечена на подчистку. (формально -- уже удалена, только физически будет удалена после того как запустится Garbage Collector)
}//до этой строки включительно мы можем использовать sr
//А здесь мы уже не можем использовать ни sw ни sr ибо окончились ОБА юзинга.
```

Точно так же как с методом, только не нужно создавать метод.

> Давайте я уточню, какая цель у разработчика языка внести такие ограничения чтобы вложенные видели внешние переменные, а наоборот не получается .

Какая цель у молотка?

Молоток это инструмент, которым можно забивать гвозди. А еще им можно вытягивать гвозди. А еще им можно разбивать орехи. А еще им можно акуратно подстукивать планки паркета. А еще его можно использовать как гнет при мариновке шашлыка. А еще много чего можно. Но цели у молотка нету.

Гвозди забивать можно и телескопом, менее удобно, но можно.

***Это просто инструмент.*** Удобный в одних случаях и неудобный в других.

Просто почитай про ***область видимости переменных*** и определи для себя лично какая "цель" тебе больше нравится.

**Лично мне ни одного разу не доводилось использовать вложенный using.**

Ты берешь инструмент который ограничивает область видимости, делаешь несколько вложений, а потом спрашиваешь а почему он делает то, что он должен делать и с какой целью? 
Прости, но вопрос глупый. **И раз уж ты написал вложенный юзинг, то это ты должен точно знать для чего конкретно ты это сделал.** Что ты хотел этим добиться? За твою логику использования тех или иных инструментов никто не отвечает. Это ты можешь нам сказать какую цель ты преследовал, но никак не кто-то тебе.

Я же у тебя не спрашиваю для чего я когда-то заморозил кусок мяса и потер его на терке :)

Если же ты хочешь что бы область видимости позволяла использовать две переменные.... То создай только один юзинг:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(targetPath, enc))
{
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sourcePath, true, enc);
  string line;

  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
  }
}
```

это же логично.

PS: я тер замороженное мясо потому, что не было мясорубки а нужен был фарш. То есть я использовал морозилку и терку как замену вообще третьему инструменту. И ни один из инструментов по прямому назначению я не использовал. Я просто использовал возможности этих инструментов.

Comment: Точно также и с циклами, условными конструкциями  и  другими блоками, я прав?

Comment: @Andrew ответ был, наверное, нечетко сформулирован, но я его дополнила уже:)

Comment: я тоже обновил свой ответ

Comment: Вы не отвечаете на вопрос ТС. Вопрос в том, какая мотивация решения разработчиков языка, а вы отвечаете «не хочешь, не пользуйся, фича так устроена, и точка». Вопрос именно в том, для чего такие правила видимости были придуманы.

Comment: (И да, как могло случиться, что вам **ни разу** не приходилось использовать вложенный `using`? Вы никогда не пользовались одновременно несколькими закрываемыми ресурсами? Я достаточно часто на практике использую 2-3 уровня вложенности `using`'ов. Разработчики языка даже планируют ввести [синтаксические улучшения](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/ab2987c20dd3da57b1e91dcef59a5d740b3542c3/meetings/2018/LDM-2018-07-09.md#using-var-feature) такого использования.)

Comment: Ну вот так -- ни разу. :) Я вообще не разработчик :D Так, просто балуюсь в свое удовольствие, когда есть время и желание. А как они еще должны были быть придуманы? Если вся суть юзинга именно в уничтожении переменных при выходе из блока кода?

Comment: Давно тебя не видел.... Куда пропадаешь?

Comment: @Andrew: Ну, собираются умные дядьки, обсуждают возможные новые правила, и думают, сделают ли они жизнь разработчика легче, или наоборот добавят головняка :)

Comment: @Andrew: Ну надо бы появляться почаще, да. Вон в субботу была встреча участников в Праге, я там был.